# Can anyone suggest how can I translate the dynamic data to different language which comes from remote API?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_localozation for localizing my app creating .arb files for different languages. However, I am not able to localize the data coming from API, how can I do so?

Comment: You would need to look at something like this....you get a certain number of translations free and then it is chargeable. https://cloud.google.com/translate

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of this kind of translation but I would like to suggest you - If possible try to add one parameter in api - which represents selected language and based on that you will get response from API. For this you have to implement translation in database as well. For some static strings you can manage it from app side and for dynamic response it will be manage using database.

Answer (score 0):

According to me if possible, get translated JSON response based on the selected language from Backend.

Because by doing this, you can reduce translating stuff from the App side.